# Error System.OutOfMemoryException when use large data

Tags: excel, rpa, blueprism

I have the following process

[image]

The process is build  like this :

**Get the data from TXT file** : File Management : Read All Text From File

**Transform Data** : Replace ([Text] ; Chr(9) ; ",")

**Write Information** : File Management : Write Text File

**Transform DATA into a collection** : File Management : Get CSV Text As Collection

The process is to transform some text file that have more than **9M** Char into a collection ( 84266 rows) but every time i am trying to execute my process the first time it is working but the second time i have the following error

> Unexpected Error of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

Comment: Probably a memory leak. You would be better off using Python.

Answer (score 1):

For the first time the memory has been occupied with the data load and converting to collection.
So upon doing any further operations without clearing or resetting will throw out of memory exception.
Either

1. Clearing the memory by calling garbage collector to free memory.
2. You can use code stage and read text data and convert it into collection.
   All the operations can be done within code stage and then the final variable or a collection send as an output.

This way you can continue for multiple times and at the end you can free up the memory once.